# Trying to sort an array, but the first element is omitted and replaced by the length of the array. (C++ Using Hoare's variation for quicksort)

Tags: arrays, pointers, data-structures, quicksort, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to sort an array that is filled with random numbers. I do not use anywhere "[]", as my professor specifically said that we should only use dynamic memory allocation for the arrays. I used malloc in this case. Here is my code:

```
void arrayClassification(int *array, int length)
{
    cout<<"This function is used to classify the created array."<<endl;

    quickSort(array, 0, length);

    cout<<"The classified array is the one below."<<endl;

    printArray(array, length);
}

void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int driver = halfArray(array, start, end);

        quickSort(array, start, driver - 1);
        quickSort(array, driver + 1, end);
    }
}

int halfArray(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    int driver, i, j;

    driver = *(array + start);

    i = start;
    j = end;

    while(true)
    {
        while (*(array + i) <= driver && i < end)
            i++;

        while (*(array + j) > driver && j > start)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            substitute(array + i, array + j);
        else
        {
            substitute(array + start, array + j);
            return j;
        }
    }
}

void substitute(int *firstArray, int *secondArray)
{
    int temporary = *firstArray;
    *firstArray = *secondArray;
    *secondArray = temporary;
}
```

The sorting works but with one problem. The first element in the array is omitted and replaced by the length of the array. Still, the length of the array is put in the correct position.

Here is the full code that you are going to need in order to run it in your machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int getArraySize();
int initializeArray(int *array, int length);
void printArray(int *array, int length);
void arrayClassification(int *array, int length);
void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end);
int halfArray(int *array, int start, int end);
void substitute(int *firstArray, int *secondArray);

int main()
{
    int sizeOfArray = getArraySize();

    int *randomNumbers = (int *)malloc(sizeOfArray *sizeof(int));

    *randomNumbers = initializeArray(randomNumbers, sizeOfArray);
    printArray(randomNumbers, sizeofArray);

    arrayClassification(randomNumbers, length);

    free(randomNumbers);
    return 0;
}

int getArraySize()
{
    int size = ZERO;

    while (size <= ZERO)
    {
        cout<<"Please give the size that you want the array to have: ";
        cin>>size;
    }

    return size-1;
}

int initializeArray(int *array, int length)
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        *(array + i) = 30 + rand() % 21;
    }

    cout<<"The array that was initialized is the one below."<<endl;

    printArray(array, length);
}

void printArray(int *array, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(array + i)<<" ";
    }
}

void arrayClassification(int *array, int length)
{
    cout<<"This function is used to classify the created array."<<endl;

    quickSort(array, 0, length);

    cout<<"The classified array is the one below."<<endl;

    printArray(array, length);
}

void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int driver = halfArray(array, start, end);

        quickSort(array, start, driver - 1);
        quickSort(array, driver + 1, end);
    }
}

int halfArray(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    int driver, i, j;

    driver = *(array + start);

    i = start;
    j = end;

    while(true)
    {
        while (*(array + i) <= driver && i < end)
            i++;

        while (*(array + j) > driver && j > start)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            substitute(array + i, array + j);
        else
        {
            substitute(array + start, array + j);
            return j;
        }
    }
}

void substitute(int *firstArray, int *secondArray)
{
    int temporary = *firstArray;
    *firstArray = *secondArray;
    *secondArray = temporary;
}
```

When I run the program, and I instruct it to give me an array with size 5, it will give the numbers
[41, 38, 42, 47, 32]

When I command it to order it, it will return
[5, 32, 38, 42, 47]

If I ask for an array of size 60 it will return
[39 41 39 49 35 36 31 37 46 39 37 45 39 39 33 37 40 42 39 45 42 38 31 41 32 45 42 37 34 47 35 43 35 42 39 40 48 41 48 42 48 32 34 35 42 38 42 31 50 49 44 40 36 46 30 39 40 40 44 42]

and if I try to order it, it will return
[30 31 31 31 32 32 33 34 34 35 35 35 35 36 36 37 37 37 37 38 38 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 40 40 40 40 40 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 43 44 44 45 45 45 46 46 47 48 48 48 49 49 50 60].

When I use the debugger, in the initializeArray function for example, instead of giving me the value of each element, it gives me the following:
array = {int *| 0x0x55d9466556d0}0x55d9466556d0
*array = {int}50

and the number does not change over the iterations

Comment: Use the debugger to set a write breakpoint on the first element of the array, see who is setting it incorrectly.

Comment: @RaymondChen That is what I tried to do. I use CLion, and it gives me just a hex value for the array, without showing each element's value. 
This is probably due to using pointers, because when I use the debugger with arrays[], it works like a charm.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The fragment you posted almost, but not quite, one. Please add the missing parts so that anyone can compile and run it **as is**. "That is what I tried to do". **Show** what you tried to do. "it gives me just a hex value for the array" **Show** what it gives you.

Comment: [This does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/xfesvMvE8). Please check what you post.

Comment: "instead of giving me the value of each element, it gives me the following" You need to learn how to use your debugger with pointers that point into arrays. The debugger doesn't know what your pointer points to. Is it a single number? Is it an array of size 10? Is it an array of size 1000000? You need to **tell** it explicitly. For example, with `gdb`  you would use a command like `print pointer[0]@size` (where `pointer` points to the first element of the array and `size` is the size of the array).

Comment: [Address sanitizer is your friend](https://godbolt.org/z/e14fEKjKv). It shows the statement that went wrong. Your program is full of off-by-one errors. `return size-1;` is one. Why do you think you need this `-1`? `for(int i = 0; i <= length; i++)` is another. `<=` in a `for` loop is *usually* a sign that the author doesn't understand half-open ranges.

Comment: Last but not least, you are writing in a language called "C-with-cout". Don't. If you want to use C++, use *idiomatic* C++. If you want to use C, use C.

Comment: And the main problem is `*randomNumbers = initializeArray(randomNumbers, sizeOfArray);`. You cannot assign an array.  What do you think `*randomNumbers = ...` is doing? Why do you think `initializeArray`  needs to return a value? What kind of value does it return in your program? Look at the compiler warnings carefully.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem thanks a lot for taking the time and giving all your answers.
I did include a return in initializeArray() and it solved my bug. But another bug emerged. I probably have to write the code from scratch for this one.
It is true that I have to learn to use my debugger with pointers. I feel like walking in the dark without it.

As far as the c-with-cout, my professor wanted to write it in C++ without STL and string, for the whole semester.

I do not understand why, but I can't do something about it.

Comment: "I did include a return in initializeArray() and it solved my bug.". This is probably wrong.  This function should return `void`. You should be aware of the fact that `*randomNumbers` means *exactly the same* as `randomNumbers[0]`, no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem It is definetely wrong. I started writing from the start.

Comment: `quickSort(array, 0, length);` should be `quickSort(array, 0, length-1);`. Your two `while` loops in `halfArray()` should check their index bounds _before_ accessing the array values, you could get seg-faults/AVs otherwise.